# Jquery Selector em um User Control, dentro de uma gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Boa tarde, tenho o seguinte código:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Style="border: 0px !important;" ID="gdvDadosHistoricoMedico" OnRowDataBound="gdvDadosHistoricoMedico_RowDataBound"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" Visible="false">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle />
                            <RowStyle />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <local:UCHistoricoAtendimentoMedico runat="server" ID="UCHistoricosAtendimentoMedicos" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Dentro do user control tenho campos que gostaria de pegar o valor com jquery ao clicar em um botão:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <governa:GVNCalendar ID="cldDataMedicamento" DiasLimiteFinal="7" Tipo="Data" runat="server" Requerido="True" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCMHora" Text="Hora"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <governa:GVNCalendar ID="cldHoraMedicamento" Tipo="Hora" ClientIDMode="AutoID" runat="server" Requerido="True" />
                                        </div>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCodPrescricaoObservacao" runat="server" />
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCodUsuarioResponsavel" runat="server" />
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfNomUsuarioResponsavel" runat="server" />
                                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                                            <button ID="GravarHorario" onclick="AdicionarNaTabela()">Clique</button>
                                        </div>
```

Qual seria o código javascript/jquery para conseguir pegar o valor? Tentei da seguinte maneira e não funcionou:

```
function AdicionarNaTabela() {    
    var cldDataMedicamento = $('#<%=cldDataMedicamento.ClientID %>').val;
    var cldHoraMedicamento = $('#<%=cldHoraMedicamento.ClientID %>').val;
    var hdfCodPrescricaoObservacao = $('#<%hdfCodPrescricaoObservacao.ClientID %>').val;
    var codProfissional = $('#<%=hdfCodUsuarioResponsavel.ClientID %>').val;
    var nomProfissional = $('#<%=hdfNomUsuarioResponsavel.ClientID %>').val;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ainda não trabalhei com JQuery no Asp.Net, mas a sintaxe para obter o valor dos itens pelo id parece correta.

Porém você já testou `('#idDoElemento.ClientID').val();` invés de `('#idDoElemento.ClientID').val;` ? Uma vez que `.val()` é um método para obter o valor do elemento, teste com o parênteses no final e provavelmente irá funcionar.

```
function AdicionarNaTabela() {    
    var cldDataMedicamento = $('#<%=cldDataMedicamento.ClientID %>').val();
    var cldHoraMedicamento = $('#<%=cldHoraMedicamento.ClientID %>').val();
    var hdfCodPrescricaoObservacao = $('#<%hdfCodPrescricaoObservacao.ClientID %>').val();
    var codProfissional = $('#<%=hdfCodUsuarioResponsavel.ClientID %>').val();
    var nomProfissional = $('#<%=hdfNomUsuarioResponsavel.ClientID %>').val();
 }
```

Comment: Realmente, esse era um dos erros do meu código, mas agora estou com outro problema, o jquery sempre recupera o valor do último User Control do grid view. Algum dica?

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos que bom que a resposta foi útil, por favor, marcá-la como útil, como resposta (já que ela resolveu sua pergunta de "Qual seria o código javascript/jquery para conseguir pegar o valor?") e fechar. Assim a pergunta do escopo inicial não ficará em aberta aguardando respostas. Quanto a essa outra dúvida, que apareceu depois (como está no seu comentário "...mas agora estou com outro problema..."), você deve detalhar melhor em uma outra pergunta para que todos os usuários (inclusive eu mesmo) possam entender melhor e te ajudar.